# viewpager with pagerAdapter not updating its views

Tags: android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I have an imageview inside view pager when user select an image though gallery I need to display recent image in view pager at  first position ,but its viewpager is not updating  with recent image.
my code:

```
public static class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    Bitmap newBitmapUploadedImage = null;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context, Bitmap newUploadedImage) {
        mContext = context;
        newBitmapUploadedImage = newUploadedImage;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int swapPicSize = 0;
        if (newBitmapUploadedImage == null) {
            swapPicSize = Singleton.galleryPicsData.size();
        } else {
            swapPicSize = Singleton.galleryPicsData.size() + 1;
        }

        return swapPicSize;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_pager_item, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(iv_user_pics);
        // imageView.setImageResource(profileViewPagerPics[position]);
       /* DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = metrics.widthPixels;
        params.leftMargin = 0;
        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
        getActivity().getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);*/
        if (Singleton.galleryPicsData.size() == 0) {
            if (Singleton.getUserProfileInfoModel().getGender()) {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.male_user_profile_photo));
            } else {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.female_user_profile_photo));

            }

        }
        if (newBitmapUploadedImage != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(newBitmapUploadedImage);
        } else {
            GalleryPics gallery_pics = Singleton.galleryPicsData.get(position);
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(ServerUtilities.BASE_IMAGE_URL + gallery_pics.getPicPath()).into(imageView);
            Log.d("user_galler_pic_img_url", "" + ServerUtilities.BASE_IMAGE_URL + Singleton.galleryPicsData.get(position).getPicPath());
            userProfilePicsProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            itemView.setTag(gallery_pics);
            container.addView(itemView);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        GalleryPics galleryPic = (GalleryPics) ((View) object).getTag();
        int position = Singleton.galleryPicsData.indexOf(galleryPic);
        if (position >= 0) {
            // The current data matches the data in this active fragment, so let it be as it is.
            return position;
        } else {
            // Returning POSITION_NONE means the current data does not matches the data this fragment is showing right now.  Returning POSITION_NONE constant will force the fragment to redraw its view layout all over again and show new data.
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried above code but no use ,still Iam getting old image ,can u suggest me how to update this viewpager

Answer (score 0):

If you see your image URL, every time you update new Image, the server would provide same URL(having no changes),but it may be different.That means first upload one image and get first image URL next upload second image and then get second URL, just compare both URL's. If both were same , Picasso doesn't update it,instead it keep calm.So use Native method that is load bitmap and show it in ImageView,it definitely update it.